# SQL Tables/Pivot tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select statement grabbing names and degrees from a database similar to the following:

```
ID_Num  F_Name  L_Name  Deg_Type     Deg_Desc                        Grad_Date
001     Tyler   Lee     Degree       Associates of Computer Science  08-Aug-2012
002     Tyler   Lee     Degree       Bachelors of Computer Science   08-Aug-2014
003     Tyler   Lee     Certificate  Supervisory Certificate         08-Aug-2013
004     Susie   Q       Degree       Associates of Mathematics       08-Aug-2014
```

I need all the data on a single line like the following, how would I do this?

```
ID_Num  F_Name  L_Name  Deg_Type  Deg_Desc                        Grad_Date    Deg_Type  Deg_Desc                       Grad_Date    Deg_Type     Deg_Desc                 Grad_Date
001     Tyler   Lee     Degree    Associates of Computer Science  08-Aug-2012  Degree    Bachelors of Computer Science  08-Aug-2014  Certificate  Supervisory Certificate  08-Aug-2013
002     Susie   Q       Degree    Associates of Mathematics       08-Aug-2014  (null)    (null)                         (null)       (null)       (null)                   (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do joins against the same table but you'll be artificially limiting the number of results to however many joins you specify (e.g. this isn't what you want):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl AS t1 LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2 LEFT JOIN... where t1.F_Name=t2.F_Name and t1.L_Name=t2.L_Name and .....
```

What you really want to do is normalize your data so that you have a separate 'student' or 'person' table, and a 'degree' table with a foreign key:

```
Table "Student":
ID F_Name L_Name
1  Tyler  Lee
1  Susie  Q

Table "Degree":
Student_ID  Desc                            Grad_Date...
1           Associates of Computer Science  08-Aug-2012...
1           Associates of Mathematics       08-Aug-2014...
```

Then your query is a simple join against the two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Student s LEFT JOIN Degree d on d.Student_ID=s.ID;
```

If you want to to have a fixed set of Degrees to choose from, you could just have 'Degree' store the different types of Degrees with their own Degree ID's, then have a mapping table of Student ID to Degree ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult because you don't know before hand (or do you?) how many degrees the person with the most degrees has. The best way to do this would be to create code in either perl or some scripting language that could (a) query your table to find the person with the most degrees, then (b) create a query dynamically with that many additional columns.

BUT if we assume that the most degrees someone has is 4, this should work:

```
SELECT ID_Num  
     , F_Name  
     , L_Name  
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Type else null end) as Deg_Type_01
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Desc else null end) as Deg_Desc_01
     , max(case when r=1 then Grad_Date else null end) as Grad_Date_01
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Type else null end) as Deg_Type_02
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Desc else null end) as Deg_Desc_02
     , max(case when r=1 then Grad_Date else null end) as Grad_Date_02
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Type else null end) as Deg_Type_03
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Desc else null end) as Deg_Desc_03
     , max(case when r=1 then Grad_Date else null end) as Grad_Date_03
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Type else null end) as Deg_Type_04
     , max(case when r=1 then Deg_Desc else null end) as Deg_Desc_04
     , max(case when r=1 then Grad_Date else null end) as Grad_Date_04
  FROM (select ID_Num, F_Name, L_name
             , Deg_Type, Deg_Desc, Grad_Date
             , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Num, F_Name, L_name) 
          from Student) as a
 GROUP BY ID_Num  
     , F_Name  
     , L_Name ;
```

I don't have access to an oracle system, so please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: We do not know beforehand how many degrees someone in the database might have, that's what makes this difficult for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: If you are conformable with scripting languages, you can (a) query the database and identify the largest number of degrees for any one person (b) push the begining of the query to a file (c) loop for max_degree to create the next three lines, changing the value of r=$loop_var and DegType_$loop_var, then (d) push the last portion of the query to the file. Then just execute the dynamically built query.